# Some GUI elements are yellow

Tags: macbook-pro, video-adapter

Recently my MacBook Pro early 2011 has a video card change (the video card issues, by the extended repair program). But now the PC has a very very odd problem: some parts of the GUI are yellow (almost always the white parts). But, if I put a window over the "yellow part" of other window then the shade is white, not yellow...

[image: Some parts of the GUI are yellow]

And its not only OSX (or the installer). It happens also on GRUB and Ubuntu.

Also, the problem dissapears after the laptop is on for an hour or something like that... but, if I restart the problem shows again.

Comment: Next time, try the hardware in front of the "staff". That way, if anything is wrong, you are already in the store.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both the fact that it is independent of the OS you are running and that it disappears after some time/warmup period indicate that this is an hardware issue. Take the laptop back to the place you've got the video card changed to have it fixed.